# Writing a shell program in linux that displays reverse arguments

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Hello I am a newbie in Linux. I'm trying to write a shell program that takes only 3 arguments and displays them in reverse order. if anyone can help thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $3 $2 $1
```

For example:

```
./script arg1 arg2 arg3
```

It would return:

```
arg3 arg2 arg1
```